# For nonnegative numbers $x + y + z = \pi$, prove that $1 \le \cos x+\cos y+\cos z \le \dfrac 3 2 $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Let $x,y,z$ be nonnegative real numbers and $x+y+z=\pi$.
>   Prove the inequality
>
> $$1 \le \cos x+\cos y+\cos z \le \frac 3 2.$$

I tried to put $z=\pi-x-y$  and then calculate the extremas of two variable function, but I failed.

Comment: What's your proof? You should include it in your question.

Comment: It's sort of hard to offer "another proof" if you haven't indicated what you _already_ have.  So you first!

Comment: i have edited ,trying to make a collection of proofs for this inequality so the students could see the methods,agess it doesnt work,lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y,z$ be the angles of a triangle $ABC$ with circumradius $R=1$ and circumcenter $O$.

If $M_{AB},M_{BC},M_{AC}$ are the midpoints of the corresponding sides, our inequality is equivalent to:

$$ R \leq OM_{AB}+OM_{AC}+OM_{BC} \leq \frac{3}{2}R. \tag{1}$$
The [Erdos-Mordell inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Mordell_inequality) proves the $\leq\frac{3}{2}R$ part.

On the other hand, by [Carnot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot's_theorem):
$$ OM_{AB}+OM_{AC}+OM_{BC} = R+r \tag{2}$$
and that proves the $\geq R$ part. We may also use just $(2)$ and Euler's inequality $R\geq 2r$ to prove $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x+\cos y+\cos z=1+\dfrac r R$$

$$1\le \cos x+\cos y+\cos z\le \dfrac 3 2 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$0\le \dfrac r R\le \dfrac 1 2$$